# ctypes error: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, ctypes, libdc1394

I'm trying to compile my program to a shared library that I can use from within Python code using ctypes.

The library compiles fine using this command:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,mylib -O3 -o mylib.so -fPIC [files] `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`
```

However, when I try and import it using ctypes

```
from ctypes import *
mylib = CDLL("/path/to/mylib.so")
print mylib.test() // Expected output: Hello World
```

I get the following error:

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Very frustrating that nobody actually shows a concrete solution. I had this issue after installing OpenCV. For me the easiest solution to remove this warning was actually to disable this driver:

```
sudo ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394
```

Comment: this is the answer you are looking for - if you arent using the hardware but using CV2!

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be permanent on debian. After a restart the link is gone. How to make it permanent?

Comment: The solution is not permanent. You can avoid the error by using a `try..except` block, but will still output an error through `stderr`

Comment: I guess that to make it permanent it should be enough to add `ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394` to `/etc/rc.local` (just before `exit 0` line)

Comment: Works like a charm! Ran into some trouble installing caffe on AWS. You saved the day.

Comment: Same issue using OpenAlpr with "alpr" command line. The issue gone using this solution; anyway it this not clear on this thread why it happens

Comment: looks like a bug in OpenCV

Answer (score 31):

`libdc1394` is a library for controlling camera hardware. I presume it comes the opencv you link in. Maybe the kernel driver does not load ? I guess there is a number of reasons why it can fail.

Maybe some OpenCV expert can answer better. But I bet the problem is on OpenCV lib side.

Some initial search for the same error message yielded results with the same reason [[1](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/171972-libdc1394-error.html), [2](http://www.ngohaibac.com/how-to-fix-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394/)]. So if you can't find `/dev/raw1394` on your file system try those.

#### UPDATE:

**It seems like this is only a warning.** The module raw1394 seems to be deprecated and some libdc1394 version might be looking for it while it disappeared with an update. Searching for it gives many results and bug reports. But it seems that the software should run fine. So if you don't really need it you can just ignore it. [[3](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/69115), [4](http://spottedsun.com/libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394/)]

Comment: We don't need to use camera hardware, is there perhaps a way of compiling without that part of OpenCV?

Comment: The fix for `/dev/raw1394` does not seem to work, I get `FATAL: Module raw1394 not found.` from `modprobe`

Comment: I saw this issue when running under a virtual machine (VMWare Fusion Ubuntu 14.04 Django Stack from Bitnami) that didn't have a USB controller installed.  After I added a USB controller to the VM this error went away.

Comment: Similarly to @goran, I saw this running a VM - VirtualBox 4.3.28 running CoreOS 647.0.0, therein running Docker 1.5.0 with a Fedora 21 image.  The error popped up with an `>>> import cv2` within the Fedora image.

Comment: "It seems like it is only a warning." This is certainly what I missed. I just assumed that the import hadn't worked, but if I just ignored it and carried on everything worked. Perhaps make this part of your answer bold?

Comment: @ArthurTacca I've edited this answer to make the finding that it's safe to ignore more prominent. The last edit was from 2012 when this finding was fresh and not so certain.

Answer (score 9):

Okay. I spent a entire day on it.

Basically, the link between `/dev/raw1394` and `/dev/null` is not permanent. You can bash into your VM, call `ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394`, but it will last only until you re-start your container.

What I had to do, that seemed to be the simplest, but not the perfect approach, is to place the linking during the startup of the Container.

I thought in Running it as a service, but seemed too much for a simple job.

The way I finally came to work, (it's not pretty, but works), is by changing the `CMD` of the Dockerfile:

`CMD sh -c 'ln -s /dev/null /dev/raw1394'; <your-script-here>`

Comment: Alternatively, you can add ```RUN echo 'ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394' >> ~/.bashrc``` and keep your CMD intact

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue with an Ubuntu precise running under VirtualBox.
First I installed OpenCV following these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV
This fixed several issues I had trying other methods but the problem with libdc1394 was still there.

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
```

I finally saw [goran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2072641/goran) comment on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689392)

So I enabled the USB controller in virtualbox.... et voila! everything works perfectly!

Thanks goran!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an additional answer.

Comment: I was not registered when answering the post, now I'm registered but do not have enough reputation to move this message into the comments, sorry

Comment: @jeremie I am using Virtual Box and ubuntu 14.04 is running on it, USB contoller is enables but still i am getting the same message - libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394 , I am running a docker container in which openCV is installed

Answer (score 4):

For folks who compiled their own opencv and encounter this error, and have no need for the firewire video capture support, you can always re-compile with 
`-D WITH_1394=OFF` option, like below:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D WITH_1394=OFF ./
```

If you turn off this option you can even loose the libdc1394-22-dev dependency (ubuntu). Though I've not personally tested this.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround in using a docker image is to mount a volume

`docker run -v /dev/null:/dev/raw1394`

Comment: How and why does this work? Will this enable me to use a webcam?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
solved by running tsu first and then debian.

problem:

```
./start-debian.sh
root@localhost:~# python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
libdc1394 error: Failed to create juju: opendir: Permission denied
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
3.2.0
root@localhost:~#

tsu
./start-debian.sh
root@localhost:~# python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.2.0
root@localhost:~#
```