# OpenCV and Numpy interacting badly

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Can anyone explain why importing cv and numpy would change the behaviour of python's struct.unpack? Here's what I observe:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from struct import pack, unpack
>>> unpack("f",pack("I",31))[0]
4.344025239406933e-44
```

This is correct

```
>>> import cv
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
>>> unpack("f",pack("I",31))[0]
4.344025239406933e-44
```

Still ok, after importing cv

```
>>> import numpy
>>> unpack("f",pack("I",31))[0]
4.344025239406933e-44
```

And OK after importing cv and then numpy

Now I restart python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from struct import pack, unpack
>>> unpack("f",pack("I",31))[0]
4.344025239406933e-44
>>> import numpy
>>> unpack("f",pack("I",31))[0]
4.344025239406933e-44
```

So far so good, but now I import cv AFTER importing numpy:

```
>>> import cv
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
>>> unpack("f",pack("I",31))[0]
0.0
```

I've repeated this a number of times, including on multiple servers, and it always goes the same way. I've also tried it with struct.unpack and struct.pack, which also makes no difference.

I can't understand how importing numpy and cv could have any impact at all on the output of struct.unpack (pack remains the same, btw).

The "libdc1394" thing is, I believe, a red-herring: [ctypes error: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394)

Any ideas?

tl;dr: importing numpy and then opencv changes the behaviour of struct.unpack.

UPDATE: Paulo's answer below shows that this is reproducible. Seborg's comment suggests that it's something to do with the way python handles subnormals, which sounds plausible. I looked into [Contexts](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#context-objects) but that didn't seem to be the problem, as the context was the same after the imports as it had been before them.

Comment: This isn't going to help you, but just for the sake of readability and simplifying the problem, does `unpack("f",pack("I",31))` produce the same result?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: Good point. Just tried it -- yes, same result... I'll edit the question to make it easier to read...

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an answer, but it's too big for a comment. I played with the values a bit to find the limits.

Without loading `numpy` and `cv`:

```
>>> unpack("f", pack("i", 8388608))
(1.1754943508222875e-38,)
>>> unpack("f", pack("i", 8388607))
(1.1754942106924411e-38,)
```

After loading `numpy` and `cv`, the first line is the same, but the second:

```
>>> unpack("f", pack("i", 8388607))
(0.0,)
```

You'll notice that the first result is the [lower limit for 32 bit floats](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008469.html). I then tried the same with `d`.

Without loading the libraries:

```
>>> unpack("d", pack("xi", 1048576))
(2.2250738585072014e-308,)
>>> unpack("d", pack("xi", 1048575))
(2.2250717365114104e-308,)
```

And after loading the libraries:

```
>>> unpack("d",pack("xi", 1048575))
(0.0,)
```

Now the first result is the lower limit for 64 bit float precision.

It seems that for some reason, loading the `numpy` and `cv` libraries, in that order, constrains `unpack` to use 32 and 64 bit precision and return 0 for lower values.

Comment: @Ben No problem :) Do test Python 3 if you haven't yet, because it seems CV checks for it and defines things differently. Also, if you comment every line in numpy's \_\_init\_\_.py the behavior goes away (at least on my system in a quick test I did), but I didn't investigate further.

Comment: I think this has to do with subnormal number handleing. The struct result seems already to round the subnormal up the smallest legal float/double (is that really supposed to happen?). Not sure how rounding flags to the CPU work, but I would guess CV changes some flags in how things get rounded.

Comment: The reasoning of course being that subnormals are very slow, so CV would want to avoid them, since for its purpose they are probably not necessary. Not sure why these flags would be changed for the whole process, but such flags are not that simple I guess.

Comment: @seberg -- thanks -- that's helpful. Can you point me to any useful resources on subnormals? It's not something I'd come across before...

Comment: @Ben, I got tricked by, the `'xi'` of course... still I guess it might have to do with denormals in some way though.