# OpenCV: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I installed OpenCV correctly on Ubuntu 14.04. However, when I run: `import cv2` I get this error message:

```
>>> import cv2
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
```

I read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394) (and the different links posted there such as [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/171972-libdc1394-error.html) interesting but finally useless one for my case) but no solution worked for me. I have no such file `/dev/raw1394`. So I installed the library:

```
sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22-dev libdc1394-22 libdc1394-utils
```

But still get the same error.

Note that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394/26028597#26028597) is the only one that works for me, however I can not pick it because I need to use camera in my application.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 23):

Maybe disabling the driver isn't the best solution, but so far this hasn't given me any problems and was the easiest way I found to solve the issue:

```
sudo ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394
```

Attention: It is not a permanent solution.

Comment: I verify that this worked for me for Ubuntu on EC2 instances

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149458/open-cv-error-failed-to-init-raw1394-persisting-in-docker/42151836#42151836) worked for me in docker.

Answer (score 2):

I vaguely remember a similar problem I once had. It has something to do with user-level permission to firewire devices. You need to add a new `udev` rule. Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/raw1394.rules` and add the following line:

```
KERNEL=="raw1394", GROUP="video"
```

Details can be found [here](https://ieee1394.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Juju_Migration#Permissions_and_ownership_for_.2Fdev.2Ffw.2A) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/libdc1394/mailman/message/23589360/).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you @nils . I will try it and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @paty.r15 Well?