# Failed to initialize libdc1394 when running caffe docker image

Tags: macos, docker, caffe

The `caffe` docker image from their github repo: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe `docker` was successfully built inside the `caffe/docker` directory on my mac:

```
Removing intermediate container 9a8cbe6385b4
Successfully built bf71c19501e5
```

However when attempting to run it an apparently well known error occurs:

```
docker run -ti caffe:cpu caffe --version


libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
caffe version 1.0.0-rc3
```

There are related questions about it here [ctypes error: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394) and here [OpenCV: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274638/opencv-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394).

So I tried the suggested fixes from them - in particular:

```
sudo ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394
```

Also:

```
docker run -v /dev/null:/dev/raw1394
```

However neither of the two fixes has any effect: still seeing:

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
```

So it may well be those answers do not address the ***specific*** problem occurring in the `caffe` docker image?

I am on `El Capitan` and running against HEAD (as of 12/17/2016) of caffe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is expected, and should be ignored.

[libdc1394 is an interface for controlling Firewire cameras.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdc1394/) Since the Docker VM does not have access to FireWire hardware, the library fails to initialize.

Caffe doesn't use libdc1394 directly; it's a dependency of OpenCV. To prevent the error, you could potentially rebuild OpenCV without the library. It's easier to just ignore the error, though.

Comment: ah I see - the caffe *did* what asked to do: report its version ;)  Now maybe I should try to do something a wee bit more challenging with it.