# Open CV error failed to init raw1394 persisting in docker

Tags: python, opencv, docker

I am running ubuntu 14.04 in a docker container and have opencv installed. Every time it runs I recieve the following error as described here: [OpenCV: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274638/opencv-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394). The technique of linking /dev/null to the device file seems to work, but it is not persistent in the docker container, and even though I have

```
RUN ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394
```

in my docker file if I run something like

```
docker-compose run <container> bash
```

the error will persist in that session. What line can I add to my docker file that will get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `ln /dev/null /dev/raw1394` inside the Dockerfile won't help you because `/dev` is not part of the docker image. You can get around this by adding a [`volume mount`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/). An example `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` would look like this:

```
[fedora@myhost ~]$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libdc1394-22-dev \
        libdc1394-22 \
        libdc1394-utils \
        python-opencv && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

[fedora@myhost ~]$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '2'
services:
  opencv:
    build: .
    command: python -c "import cv2; print cv2.__version__"
    volumes:
      - /dev/null:/dev/raw1394

[fedora@myhost ~]$ sudo docker-compose up  
Recreating fedora_opencv_1
Attaching to fedora_opencv_1
opencv_1  | 2.4.8
fedora_opencv_1 exited with code 0
```