# Setting up caffe on Ubuntu 14.04 but facing errors when running classify.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, caffe

I'm installing Caffe on an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual server with CUDA installed (without driver) using https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM as inspiration. I've installed all the necessary dependencies and have followed all the instructions step by step but get the error below when I try to test the installation.

In regards to the step:
" Modify python/classify.py to add the --print_results option"

I had amended the code via in classify.py to be identical to the official caffe distribution. Not sure if that is the step that is causing the problem but thought I'd add that extra piece of information just in case.

The error i get is as below:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/caffe$ sudo python python/classify.py --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg foo

libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/classify.py", line 14, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "/home/vagrant/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/vagrant/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 15, in <module>
    import caffe.io
  File "/home/vagrant/caffe/python/caffe/io.py", line 2, in <module>
    import skimage.io
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    reset_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 89, in reset_plugins
    _load_preferred_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 69, in _load_preferred_plugins
    _set_plugin(p_type, preferred_plugins['all'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 81, in _set_plugin
    use_plugin(plugin, kind=plugin_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 251, in use_plugin
    _load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 295, in _load
    fromlist=[modname])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/matplotlib_plugin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
    encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, locale name is usually a language (and optional encoding), not just encoding. What do you have in `LANG` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Check your current shell environment, these variables: `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`:

```
set | grep -a '^LC_ALL=.'; set | grep -a '^LC_CTYPE=.';
set | grep -a '^LANG=.'; set | grep -a '^LANGUAGE=.'
```

Likely the first printed line will contain one of these variables equal to 'UTF-8'. This is wrong.

A proper locale should have language and optional country and encoding specification, like 'en' or 'en_US' or 'ru_RU.UTF-8'. There's a special locale 'C' used as fallback.

So you may redefine your locale permanently in `/etc/default/locale` (don't forget to reload your settings, the easiest way is to logoff/logon), or simply override it for a particular command:

```
> LC_ALL=C python python/classify.py --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg foo
```

Regarding libdc1394: if you don't need interaction with FireWire check [ctypes error: libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394)

Comment: Hi user3159253 thanks so much for taking time to look at my question. So I took your advice and ran the command again changing the shell environment for that particular command before I redefined my locale permanently. I still get the libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394 error although I don't get the errors in regards to the uknown locale.

Comment: Well, then you need to update your question :) And it would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394 :)